# Pig: Cast error while grouping data

Tags: apache-pig

This is the code that I am trying to run. Steps:

1. Take an input (there is a .pig_schema file in the input folder)
2. Take only two fields (chararray) from it and remove duplicates
3. Group on one of those fields

The code is as follows:

```
x = LOAD '$input' USING PigStorage('\t'); --The input is tab separated
x = LIMIT x 25;
DESCRIBE x;
-- Output of DESCRIBE x:
-- x: {id: chararray,keywords: chararray,score: chararray,time: long}

distinctCounts = FOREACH x GENERATE keywords, id; -- generate two fields
distinctCounts = DISTINCT distinctCounts; -- remove duplicates
DESCRIBE distinctCounts;
-- Output of DESCRIBE distinctCounts;
-- distinctCounts: {keywords: chararray,id: chararray}

grouped = GROUP distinctCounts BY keywords; --group by keywords
DESCRIBE grouped; --THIS IS WHERE IT GIVES AN ERROR
DUMP grouped;
```

When I do the grouped, it gives the following error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats  - 
ERROR: org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

keywords is a chararray and Pig should be able to group on a chararray. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Input file:

```
0000010000014743       call for midwife    23      1425761139
0000010000062069       naruto 1    56      1425780386
0000010000079919       the following    98     1425788874
0000010000081650       planes 2    76      1425721945
0000010000118785       law and order    21     1425763899
0000010000136965       family guy    12    1425766338
0000010000136100       american dad    19      1425766702
```

.pig_schema file

```
{"fields":[{"name":"id","type":55},{"name":"keywords","type":55},{"name":"score","type":55},{"name":"time","type":15}]}
```

Comment: Please share the input file for analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pig is not able to identify the value of keywords as chararray.Its better to go for field naming during initial load, in this way we are explicitly stating the field types.

```
x = LOAD '$input' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (id:chararray,keywords:chararray,score: chararray,time: long);
```

**UPDATE :**

Tried the below snippet with updated .pig_schema to introduce score, used '\t' as separator and tried the below steps for the input shared.

```
  x = LOAD 'a.csv' USING PigStorage('\t'); 
 distinctCounts = FOREACH x GENERATE keywords, id; 
 distinctCounts = DISTINCT distinctCounts;
 grouped = GROUP distinctCounts BY keywords; 
 DUMP grouped;
```

Would suggest to use unique alias names for better readability and maintainability.

**Output :**

```
    (naruto 1,{(naruto 1,0000010000062069)})
    (planes 2,{(planes 2,0000010000081650)})
    (family guy,{(family guy,0000010000136965)})
    (american dad,{(american dad,0000010000136100)})
    (law and order,{(law and order,0000010000118785)})
    (the following,{(the following,0000010000079919)})
    (call for midwife,{(call for midwife,0000010000014743)})
```

Comment: I think pig is identifying the value of keywords as chararray since "DESCRIBE X" shows it as a chararray. Also, there is a .pig_schema file which is being loaded (which I had not mentioned before). Updated the question.

Comment: @AlastorMoody: In the .pig_schema shared I see only 3 fields : id, keywords and time. What about score field ?

Comment: Sorry. Updated it. Since I removed irrelevant fields from x for clarity, I had to remove fields from the pig schema and messed up doing that.

Comment: @AlastorMoody : I tried the above steps did not see any issues, see updated answer for details.

Comment: I am using pig 0.12. Are you using a newer version? Thanks a lot for doing this.

Comment: @AlastorMoody: In my local I have used : Apache Pig version 0.14.0 (r1640057) , I don't think its issue specific to a version.

Comment: I tried running the exact same code that you posted and created new test files with the same data as in the stackoverflow question and it works. However, if my old code was not reading the keywords as chararray, then describe should not show it as chararray, right? That seems to distract one from the issue.

Comment: @AlastorMoody : Yeah, it should not have shown as chararray during describe. If its causing an issue, I would suggest to declare the schema of the fields during LOAD command.

Comment: Yes. As a workaround I think I will specify the schema manually. However I have more than 40 fields and the schema changes occasionally, so I was hoping I would not have to do that.

Comment: @AlastorMoody : Other alternative would be to add explicit cast wherever keywords is getting used :  (chararray)keywords.

Comment: Tried that, but I still get a casting error. I am pretty much at my wits end here. I tried specifying the schema manually (load 'xyz' AS (id: chararray,keywords: chararray,score: chararray,time: long)), but that didn't work as well. Is there a known bug or something in v0.12 that I am missing?

Comment: @AlastorMoody : I would suggest to install 0.14 in your local system and try this use case. This would help you in knowing if its an issue specific to a version.

Comment: Sure. I will try that. Thanks! I talked with other people in the team and they had similar issues with 0.12 which got resolved once they upgraded.